# how to join same record with multiple elements?

Tags: sql

I've a below two tables

```
tableA
id,nameId,locationId,addressId
100,bob,ny,abc
200,bean,uk,zx

tableB
Ids
bob
ny
abc
200,
bean
```

expected output

```
id,nameId,locationId,addressId,nameIdMatch,locationIdMatch,addressIdMatch
100,bob,ny,abc,bob,ny,abc
200,bean,uk,zx,bean,uk,
```

This can be done, joining one by one out of these key (`nameId,locationId,addressId`) with `tableB` and then create a expected output.

Is there any more better way where I could achieve this using single join ?

Thanks

Comment: If your `tableA` has a reference ids to 3 tables, how are you supposed get the data from the other 2 tables if you insist on only using 1 join???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I would say that it is an awful design but probably you would simply ignore that).
You can do it even without a join just for the sake of saying you have done in another way:

```
create table tableA (id int,nameId varchar(10),locationId varchar(10),addressId varchar(10));
insert into tableA (id,nameId,locationId,addressId) values
(100,'bob','ny','abc'),
(200,'bean','uk','zx');

create table tableB (Ids  varchar(10));
insert into tableB (Ids) values 
('bob'),
('ny'),
('abc'),
('200'),
('bean');

select *,
  case when exists (select * from tableB where nameId = ids) then nameId end as NameIdMatch,
  case when exists (select * from tableB where locationId = ids) then locationId end as LocationIdMatch,
  case when exists (select * from tableB where addressId = ids) then addressId end as AddressIdMatch
from tableA;
```

| id | nameid | locationid | addressid | nameidmatch | locationidmatch | addressidmatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | bob | ny | abc | bob | ny | abc |
| 200 | bean | uk | zx | bean | *null* | *null* |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GlbVHnsr)